# Content related to a topic from a text file

Tags: lucene, nlp, text-mining

Do we have any API that can identity content from a text file related to a particular topic?

For example I have a text file having 5000 lines of text in it.

I want to extract the text related to `TOPIC ABC`. Does lucene or any other api do that? Any idea?

I have used Lucene for identifying the documents that contain a particular `WORD`but would like to know if we have any api that extracts the content from a file related to a particular topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question, but from the information you have supplied it is clear you have a couple of options.

**Option 1:** Use an API

You could use the Thomson Reuters [Open Calais platform](http://www.opencalais.com/) which is the best that I have ever came across available for developers. However, it I can imagine it would get expensive over time. They provide a [demo](http://www.opencalais.com/opencalais-demo/) on their site which is worth checking out.

**Option 2:** Extend Lucene's VSM

When I say extend Lucene, I don't mean you need to. There is open-source projects readily available to be taken advantage of. For example, [Luence-LDA](https://github.com/stepthom/lucene-lda) which allows queries over Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA). This particular project hasn't been updated in about 3/4 years so it may want to fork it or build your own.